# React | How to Control Child Component after Lifting State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How could I lift the state and still be able to have the parent component tell the elements of the children component whether or not they should be visible?

I was advised to have my `<List />` handle its own state for each `<li />`

```js
class HeroList extends Component {
  state = {
    show: false
  };

  handleShow = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  };

  getColor = () => {
    if (this.state.show) {
      if (this.props.isCorrect) {
        return "green";
      } else {
        return "red";
      }
    }
    return "";
  };

  render() {
    console.log('rendered list again')
    const { name, color } = this.props;
    const { show } = this.state;
    return (
      <li onClick={this.handleShow} className={this.getColor()}>
        {name}
        <span className={show ? "show" : "hide"}>{color}</span>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

However, when I call my shuffle method from the Parent Component, even though the `<List/>` component goes through a **new render**, its state does not go back to the initial state: i.e `show:false` remains as `show:true`

```js
export default class Heroes extends Component {
  state = {
    heroes: [
      { name: "Aquaman", color: "orange", id: 1 },
      { name: "Batman", color: "black", id: 2 },
      { name: "Green Lantern", color: "green", id: 3 },
      { name: "SuperMan", color: "blue", id: 4 },
      { name: "SpiderMan", color: "red", id: 5 }
    ]
  };

  /****** SHUFFLE METHOD ******/
  handleShuffle = () => {
    this.setState({
      heroes: [...this.state.heroes.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)]
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { heroes } = this.state;
    const correctIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (heroes.length - 1));
    const correctHero = heroes[correctIndex];

    const hero = heroes.map(hero => (
      <HeroList
        key={hero.id}
        name={hero.name}
        color={hero.color}
        isCorrect={correctHero.color === hero.color}
      />
    ));

    return (
      <>
        <h6>React Controlled Components</h6>
        <Question key={correctHero.id} color={correctHero.color} />
        <button onClick={this.handleShuffle}>shuffle heroes</button>
        <ul>{hero}</ul>
      </>
    );
  }
}

// Question
const Question = ({ color }) => <h2>What Hero wears {color}</h2>;
```

I was then advised to lift the state up to the Parent Component and pass the state down as a prop, but then I hit a blocker where when `show: true` for one `<li />` becomes true for all of them on the very first `onClick` event.

**Question:** How could I lift the state up but still control each `<li/>` to change individually `onClick`?

You can see the problem in action here, please feel free to fork it => [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qqmko3xl04)

Answer (score 2):

You need to maintain list of show status in parent component state and manipulate them based on clicked hero item.

Solution here

[image: Edit react-controlled-components]

Comment: Thank you for your help @Ganapati V S, however, your suggestion is doing a `toggle` on each click, also the `shuffle( )` isn't setting the list items back to false. Thoughts?

Comment: If you don't want the toggle you can do `newShow[heroIndex] = false` in line `26` in `Heroes.js`. Also, yes, `shuffle()` should reset show status. Updated! Does it work?

Comment: setting `newShow[heroIndex] = false` creates a bug where nothing happens to the List and everything keeps shuffling

Comment: Also each adjacent click is erroneously shuffling the `{color}` from the `<Question />` component.

Comment: my bad, you should do `newShow[heroIndex] = true`(Updated!), color is updating because you are computing `isCorrect` using `correctIndex` in `render` which uses `Math.random()`. in each render value could be different.

Comment: Moving `correctIndex` to state is works as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187087/discussion-between-ganapati-v-s-and-null-istrue).